# How can I create calendar alerts when specific events are about to happen with certain keywords in?

Tags: calendar, alert, sharepoint-calendar, notifications

**SharePoint 2013**

I would like to set up alerts on calendar events from a few calendars. There are 4 calendars on our site (conference room, board room, etc.). They get events thrown in by everyone in the company. I'd like to set up a filter or search to find 3 or 4 key words and alert my department's email address 30 min before the event takes place (I don't care when the events are created, we just need a heads up on them happening).

Would the most simple solution be to create one more calendar that pulls from the others, or use RSS, subscription, workflows, or some sort of custom web part list and add alerts to those?.
I don't want to rely on those who create the events to always add us.

Comment: You can create a job to look for incaming events and send the alerts by email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Web Services in SharePoint 2013 Workflows in SharePoint Designer 2013 to query the lists api or to query the search api (or any of the sharepoint REST API) . Follow this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567558.aspx

[image]

You need to query several lists, so I recommend using to search api to query by the event content type as described here:

[How to get all items with a specific content type using REST Api](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115941/how-to-get-all-items-with-a-specific-content-type-using-rest-api)

Query including your 3,4 keywords.

You also need to run workflow continuosly, daily basis. You can achieve this by seeting up a event timer job if you have access/permissions to do this on server side, and if you don't, you create your workflow with a 24h pause stage. [Schedule a workflow to run everyday](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138098/schedule-a-workflow-to-run-everyday/138104)

Hope this helps.