# How do you get the ContentType name for the items returned using SEARCH API

Tags: search, rest, search-api

I use SP SEARCH api and below is my enpdoint:

/_api/search/query?querytext=%27matrix%27&&$expand=ContentType&rowlimit=5

It doesn't seem to show anywhere that "$expand" is supported. I also tried to match the stringId from ContentType to another REST call to this endpoint:

/_api/web/contentTypes

But I get a result that is specific to that site only.

**The question is simple: How do I get the Content Type Name for the results in SEARCH API?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
https://siteurl/_api/search/query?querytext="keyword to search"&selectproperties='Title,ContentType'
```

This should help

Comment: This did it! That was pretty simple. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question?  [How to get all items with a specific content type using REST Api](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115941/how-to-get-all-items-with-a-specific-content-type-using-rest-api)

```
http://yoursite.domain.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contenttype:CONTENT_TYPE_NAME'
```